# Make a pipe conditional on non-empty return

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there a way to pipe the output of one function to another, but only if there *is* an output?

Comment: Very similar: [How to pipe output from one process to another but only execute if the first has output?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/13326/80216) and [Check if pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn’t](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/33049/80216) (on U&L)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following `ifnotempty` function pipes its input to the command passed as an argument, except that it does nothing if the input is empty. Use it to pipe `source --foo` into `sink --bar` by writing `source --foo | pipe_if_not_empty sink --bar`.

```
pipe_if_not_empty () {
  head=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; echo a)
  head=${head%a}
  if [ "x$head" != x"" ]; then
    { printf %s "$head"; cat; } | "$@"
  fi
}
```

Design notes:

- I would expect this implementation to work on all POSIX/Unix platforms, though strictly speaking it is not standards-compliant: it relies on `dd` not reading more than the one byte it's told to read on its standard input.
- I think `head -c 1` would be a suitable replacement for `dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null` on Linux.
- On the other hand, `head -n 1` would not be suitable because `head` typically buffers its input and may read more than the one line it outputs — and since it's reading from a pipe, the extra bytes are just lost.
- `read -r head` and even `read -r -n 1 head` are not suitable here because if the first character is a newline, `head` would be set to the empty string, making it impossible to distinguish between empty input and input starting with a blank line.
- We can't just write `head=$(head -c 1)` because if the first character is a newline, command substitution would strip the final newline, making it impossible to distinguish between empty input and input starting with a blank line.
- In bash, ksh or zsh, you can replace `cat` by `</dev/stdin` for a microscopic performance gain.

---

If you don't mind storing the whole intermediate data in memory, here is a very slightly simpler implementation of `pipe_if_not_empty`.

```
pipe_if_not_empty () {
  input=$(cat; echo a);
  if [ "x$input" != x"a" ]; then
    { printf %s "${input%a}"; } | "$@"
  fi
}
```

Here is a slightly simpler implementation with the following caveats:

- The data produced by the source is considered empty if and only if it consists solely of newline characters. (This may in fact be desirable.)
- The data fed into the sink ends with exactly one newline character, no matter how many newlines the data produced by the source ends with. (This is could be a problem.)

Again, the whole data is stored in memory.

```
pipe_if_not_empty () {
  input=$(cat);
  if [ "x$input" != x"" ]; then
    { printf '%s\n' "${input}"; } | "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Could it be re-directed into `less -r` if its not empty?

Answer (score 29):

This should work for you

```
$ --a function-- | [ xargs -r ] --another function--
```

An example

```
$ echo -e "\n\n" | xargs -r ls
$ # No output. ls did not run.
$ echo -e "\n\n1" | xargs -r ls
ls: cannot access 1: No such file or directory
```

It's simple but it should work for you.
If your "a function" sends an empty string or even a newline down the pipeline, xargs -r, will prevent passage through to "another function".

Reference for xargs: http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=x/xargs

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
Do not run command if standard input contains only blanks.
```

Comment: could it be piped into `less -r`?

Comment: xargs does not function as a pipe

Comment: That's great. `xargs --no-run-if-empty` doesn't run the command on blank input (including new lines), as demonstrated by your example. Whereas `ifne` only doesn't run the command if the input is completely empty. (`echo -e "\n\n" | ifne ls` runs `ls`).

Answer (score 16):

[**ifne(1)**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/ifne.1.html) from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) does exactly that. Moreutils is available as a package at least in Debian and Ubuntu, probably in other distros as well.

Answer (score 5):

The function below tries to read the 1st byte, and if successfull echos that byte and cats the rest. Should be efficient and 100% portable.

```
if_read() {
    IFS="" read -rN 1 BYTE && { echo -nE "$BYTE"; cat; } | "$@";
}
```

Test cases:

```
$ echo -n | if_read wc -c
$ echo | if_read wc -c
1
$ echo -en "\nX" | if_read wc -c
2
$
```

Comment: This function fails for me when I run `echo -en "\nX" | pipe_if_not_empty mail -s "Subject line here" foo@bar.com`. It thinks that `line` and `here` are both recipients of the e-mail, not tokens in the subject. I have to escape the `"` surrounding the subject to get it to work. However, the `pipe_if_not_empty` function from the accepted answer works for me even without escaping anything.

Comment: Nice but note that it's not binary-safe because it cannot handle `\0`. E.g. `echo -ne "\0foo" | if_read od -aAn` lacks the "nul".

Answer (score 3):

At least something like this works:

`yourcommand | if [ $(wc -c) -gt "0" ]; then yourothercommand; fi`

Please note that the above will consider line feeds and other special characters as output, so an empty line passed to that if statement will be considered as an output. Just raise the -gt limit if your output should usually be higher than 1 byte :)

Comment: `yourothercommand` never sees the output of `yourcommand`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `sender | receiver`:

```
tester () { local a=$(</dev/stdin); if [[ $a ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$a" | receiver; fi; }
sender | tester
```

Or you could make it more general purpose by changing it to accept the receiving program as an argument as in Gilles' answer:

```
tester () { local a=$(</dev/stdin); if [[ $a ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$a" | "$@"; fi; }
sender | tester receiver
```